"Error extracting support files. Build may fail." in e2studio IDE
An error shows during compilation in e2studio IDE for the Renesas project with RZ/A1H MPU:

[ERROR] Error extracting support files. Build may fail.

I also get:
Loading repos summaries...
Parsing cached content file "\..\Packages\.cache\.content_www_keil_com_pack_index_pidx.xml"...
File does not exist, ignored.
Identifying installed packages...
Found no installed packages." during debugging mode.

I tried installing packages from Renesas Toolchain manager. But it failed to.
So, I cannot enter into the Debug mode.
How do I resolve this?
